# Observer for Android LiveData not called (but it is with observeForever)

Tags: android, realm, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I have a `Fragment` on a `ViewPager` which shows a list of items. Clicking one, opens a new details-`Activity` where you can manipulate this item (e.g. change the name). When you return to the list, I want the list / item to be reflect the updates.

I'm using a combination of `Realm` and `LiveData` (`RealmChangeListener` is added and updates the `value` of the actual `LiveData`) which works fine.

Plus, I'm using the "reobserve" approach (#3) from https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/architecture-components-pitfalls-part-1-9300dd969808 which works fine when the fragments of the ViewPager are re-added.

---

When altering the list-items on the list-fragment itself, the observer is called and everything is fine. But when changes are made *from a different activity* (details) the LiveData-observer is not called.

However, when using `observeForever()` instead of `observe(LifecycleOwner)` the observer *is called* even when changes are made from the other activity (which is what I want).

---

The fragment is only *stopped* (and resumed when you come back from the details to the list). It is not detached, not destroyed, its views still exist etc. so the observeForever-observer can update the UI just fine (even when not visible).

But I'd like to use the "add and forget"-approach of the normal `observe()` where I don't need to remove the observer.

---

Does anyone has an idea why the observer is not called? As mentioned the fragment is only stopped and the views do still exist (and it is called when the changes happen from the same activity but not in a different one).

Because of `observeForever()` working, I can only think of a buggy lifecycle where the observer is marked as "stopped" but not as "resumed" when coming back?

---

#### edit 1

As asked, here's the code to get the `RealmResult` as a `LiveData` (from a [blog post at realm](https://academy.realm.io/posts/android-architecture-components-and-realm/)):

```
Realm.getDefaultInstance()
  .where<Model>()
  .findAllAsync()
  .asLiveData()

fun <T : RealmModel> RealmResults<T>.asLiveData() = RealmResultsRealmData(this)

class RealmResultsRealmData<T : RealmModel>(private val results: RealmResults<T>) : LiveData<RealmResults<T>>() {

    private val listener = RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<T>> { realmResults ->
        value = if (realmResults.isValid) realmResults else null
    }

    // region LiveData

    override fun onActive() {
        results.addChangeListener(listener)
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        results.removeChangeListener(listener)
    }

    // endregion
}
```

This is working just fine. My `ViewModel` calls `realm.close()` in `onCleared()` so this should be fine as well.

As mentioned, I don't think the problem is at the realm-side because it works when using `observeForever()` but not when using the normal `observe()` on the `LiveData`. Realm just fills the `LiveData` and this is verified working (using `observeForever()`).

My best guess ist still the lifecycle of the observer when using `observe()`. But I don't get why it's not called when the fragment gets "resumed". [The docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html#observe_livedata_objects) say "observers also receive an update when they change from an inactive to an active state".

It is not defined whats an "active" state is but I guess it's at least "started" and my fragment gets to this state when I come back from the details-activity. So the observer should be called with the latest value of the `LiveData`? In contrast, when using `observeForever()` the observer is called right away while I'm still at the details-activity (because the fragment is only stopped but still active?!).

Comment: How do you manage the UI thread Realm lifecycle ref count? Is the query sync or async?

Comment: Also can I see how you wrap the RealmResults as LiveData? There is a solution in the official examples and i do not know if you are using those

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I've added some code to show how to get from `RealmResults` to `LiveData`. So yes, I'm using the "official example" to do this.

Comment: But I don't know what you mean with "UI thread Realm lifecycle ref count". Can you explain some more?

Comment: Like, where do you open/close Realm

Comment: `For every Realm.getDefaultInstance() you invoke, you need to call realm.close() on that instance before it’s GC’d.` from the article you linked :P

Comment: @EpicPandaForce right - I do this (as mentioned) in `onCleared()` of the `ViewModel` so this should be fine. Plus, it works when using `observeForever()` with the same `ViewModel` so I don't think it's related to that.

Comment: I am having the same issue as well. Data that is saved in a separate activity, (still using the default realm instance), does not update the LiveData event. For now I have created an activity result and pass the data back, but its not ideal.

Comment: *Update on my last comment* - For me if I unbind and rebind the change listener in the `onResume()` lifecycle event I am able to see the new data. I believe this is an issue with the observer and not necessarily realm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `addChangeListener()` **does not call the listener with the current value**.

The [LiveRealmResults](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/architectureComponentsExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/arch/livemodel/LiveRealmResults.java)-class from the realm-examples does this manually in the constructor (when the result is already loaded, so only for *synchronous* queries).

```
if (results.isLoaded) {
    // we should not notify observers when results aren't ready yet (async query).
    // however, synchronous query should be set explicitly.
    value = results
}
```

For *async*-ones, the listener will only be called when the query returns (so this works most of the times because the `LiveData` is already *active* (`onActive()` has been called from the system and the listener has been added).

---

In my case (where the model is changed **while the `LiveData` is *inactive***), the listener is **not called** when it gets active again (as said, `addChangeListener()` does not call the listener with the current value).

So my UI (observing the `LiveData`) **is not notified** and still shows the old data.

---

**Workaround**

I workaround this, by adding the same lines from the example-constructor to `onActive()` (copied from the example) as well. This way, the listener **is called** with the current value when `LiveData` gets active (but not on the initial call when the result is not loaded - so no double calls).

```
override fun onActive() {
    super.onActive()

    if (results.isValid) { // invalidated results can no longer be observed.
        results.addChangeListener(listener)

        if (results.isLoaded) {
            value = results
        }
    }
}
```